# Is it possible to convert JPEG file to PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf

Is it possible to convert a JPEG file to a PDF file in Java?

Tried the below:

```
// pdf converter
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\ss.jpeg"));
document.open();
Image image = Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("C:\\file.pdf"));
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

> Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
> `getClass()` from the type Object

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
public class CreatePDF {
        public static void main (String args[]) {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.addAuthor("authorname");
            document.addTitle("This is my pdf doc");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\file.pdf"));
            document.open();
            Image image = Image.getInstance("C:\\img.png");
            document.add(image);
            document.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **nameOfClass.class** instead of **getClass()**.

For Example Refer following code snippet :

**Like as your :**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\ss.jpeg"));
    document.open();
    Image image = Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("C:\\file.pdf"));
    document.add(image);
    document.close();

    }
}
```

**Change it to :**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\ss.jpeg"));
        document.open();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(Test.class.getResource("C:\\file.pdf"));
        document.add(image);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i face the below error.
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:370)

Also, the screenshot "ss" is unable to open (File can't open)

Comment: @saratkumar : if this answer solved your problem ..Could you please accept this answer by clicking on correct tick mark

Comment: @saratkumar I am facing the same issue, NullPointer Exception. What fix you gave ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ImageToPdf {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Document document = new Document();
        String input = "resources/GMARBLES.png"; // .gif and .jpg are ok too!
        String output = "resources/GMARBLES.pdf";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            writer.open();
            document.open();
            document.add(Image.getInstance(input));
            document.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```